# remove adjacent duplicates from string

Tags: r, string, duplicates

I am analyzing song lyrics. These often contain "la la la" and "oh oh oh". Basically meaningless words. I want to remove these repeated words, or at least identify them first.
Below is some code that almost does the job.

```
test <- data.frame(c("la la la yeah the meaning of life vive la France yeah yeah yeah"))
names(test) <- "V1"
test$V1 <- as.character(test$V1)

d <- unlist(strsplit(test$V1, split=" "))
test$V2 <- paste(d[-which(duplicated(d))], collapse = ' ')
test$V2
```

So, duplicates are removed, but a bit too rigorously: "la yeah the meaning of life vive France"
preferably I would like to keep the "la" from "Vive la France", while the first "la"from "la la la" can be removed as well. similaryl, the first "yeah" should not be removed", but the three last ones should be. 
This means a single duplicate embedded between dissimilar words should be retained, while duplicate adjacent words should all be removed. 
The reason while the code above does not work is that it ignores the order of the words in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'll need `rle` to identify the order and select only those words with length 1.

```
sapply(strsplit(test$V1, split=" "), function(x) {
   paste(with(rle(x), values[lengths == 1]), collapse = " ")
})
#[1] "yeah the meaning of life vive la France"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the rle function. It does do the job perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, honestly I never saw the check mark option. How unobservant of me :-( I'll mark the previous reply on my answers as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `gsub` here with a positive lookahead assertion which checks for an adjacent duplicate word:

```
input <- "la la la yeah the meaning of life vive la France yeah yeah yeah"
output <- gsub("(\\S+)( \\1)+", "", input, perl=TRUE)
output <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", output)
output

[1] "yeah the meaning of life vive la France"
```

If `sub` encounters a word followed by a space and the same word, it just replaces with empty string, thereby removing the prior duplicate.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks...when I answered I read no further than the title which refers to adjacent duplicates.  The OP did not clearly show the expected output.